# Tika in ColdFusion's SOLR throwing NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: solr, coldfusion, apache-tika

We're using the version of SOLR that comes with ColdFusion 10 (3.4). I have

```
<entity 
name="attachment" 
dataSource="dastream"
processor="TikaEntityProcessor"
url="contentdatafile"
dataField="items.CONTENTDATAFILE"
format="text">
```

in my data-config.xml.
When I try to run it, I get this is the error log:
Full Import failed:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tika/parser/AutoDetectParser

Does anyone know how to fix this? Doesn't SOLR 3.4 have Tika?

Full Trace:

```
 Feb 06, 2015 11:04:45 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: Full Import failed:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tika/parser/AutoDetectParser
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.findClass(SolrResourceLoader.java:383)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.loadClass(DocBuilder.java:1009)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.getEntityProcessor(DocBuilder.java:823)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:552)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:268)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:187)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:359)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:427)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:408)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:401)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:363)
    ... 11 more

Feb 06, 2015 11:04:45 AM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 rollback
INFO: start rollback
Feb 06, 2015 11:04:45 AM org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2 rollback
INFO: end_rollback
Feb 06, 2015 11:04:45 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [jimspdf] webapp=/solr path=/select params={command=status&clean=false&qt=/dataimport&commit=true} status=0 QTime=0
```

Comment: Can you post the full trace?

Comment: Did you make sure you added the Tika Jars to your classpath, along with all their dependencies?

Comment: Yes, looking at the "cause" ie ClassNotFoundException it looks like you may be missing some jars.

Comment: It looks like they're in the ColdFusion classpath: D:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/lib/tagsoup-1.2.jar;  D:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/lib/tika-core-0.6.jar;  D:/ColdFusion10/cfusion/lib/tika-parsers-0.6.jar;

Comment: Yes, tika-core-0.6.jar does contain that class. However, unless it is a red herring, ClassNotFoundException means it is not being detected/loaded for some reason. No idea why though.

Comment: I gave up and switched to a stand-alone newer version of SOLR.

Answer (score 0):

When i was using Tika with ColdFusion, i also used a javaloader. See project https://github.com/cfjedimaster/getallthetexts, it was helpful for me.